# access sharepoint api using user credentials

Tags: go, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

how to access sharepoint using api requests with headers having user credentials.
For example getting list of all the documents that are there in sharepoint.
Is there a way where we can send http request along with user credentials and get response from sharepoint, If not please specify a method to achieve this.i am developing this application in golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing this. Since you have on-prem environment, you can try following link.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220918/sharepoint-2010-get-rest-api-fetch-data-behind-authentication-using-javascript/221183#221183

Comment: ohh its from javascript, i dont want it to be directly from browser, it should be programmatic

Comment: In such case you can use `client side object model`. Where you need to create connection to SP site which will provide you the `client context`, later you can use any CRUD operation on SharePoint.

Comment: and it does ask for credentials to connect.

Comment: i have the credentials, when i send a request to http://sp.example/_api/web/lists along with username and password in http header,  it says System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: My Question is, what cant you use MS.SP.Client if you have power of SP. SP REST API doesnt have authentication mechanism. You need to authenticate against your Site Collection and use the same permission.